# View Errors in Intellij Project

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij version 8. How can I view the warnings or errors for an entire project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366569/104891) which is up to date. The original answer here was for older IDEA version when there was no automatic compilation and the Problems view.

Comment: Must have looked over that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please provide a summary here in case the link goes down? :) Thanks!

Comment: @avalancha I've updated the answer.

Comment: The Intellij link is broken

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation, wanting to view all warnings and errors in RubyMine / IntelliJ IDEA in a single collective space.

The link above was helpful. For the lazy, here are the steps:

1. Install the *Eclipse Mode* plugin via **Settings | Plugins**
2. Use this in combination with the "Scope / Problems" mode of the Project View