# How to view the list of compile errors in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I am looking for a way to view all compile errors in IntelliJ, similar to how they are displayed in Eclipse.  I tried searching here and Google but have not really found a solution.  I really like IntelliJ, I recently converted to it from Eclipse, and I hope this is just something I am missing and not a fundamental deficiency.

Comment: You could maybe add an eclipse screenshot of what you want to have with Intellij

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View Errors in Intellij Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644861/view-errors-in-intellij-project)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I think this comes closest to what you wish:

(From [IntelliJ IDEA Q&A for Eclipse Users](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html)):

[image]

The above can be combined with a recently introduced option in Compiler settings to get a view very similar to that of Eclipse.

Things to do:

1. Switch to 'Problems' view in the Project pane: 
    
    [image]
2. Enable the setting to compile the project automatically : 
    
    [image]
3. Finally, look at the Problems view: 
    
    [image]

Here is a comparison of what the same project (with a compilation error) looks like in Intellij IDEA 13.xx and Eclipse Kepler:

[image]

[image]

Relevant Links:
The maven project shown above : https://github.com/ajorpheus/CompileTimeErrors

FAQ For 'Eclipse Mode' / 'Automatically Compile' a project : http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1122

Comment: Plugin "Eclipse Mode" not available for IDEA 13.

Comment: Apparently this "problems" toolbar is only available if you select the "auto compile" mode.  see here: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/problems-tool-window.html

Comment: I switched to problems instead of projects and I also  enabled the 'Build project automatically' but I still don't see the problems/ compiler errors per se. I just see the classes that have the errors. Could anyone help with that...?

Comment: Does this work _at all_ for Scala? I can't seem to make it happen.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only shows compilation errors, it doesn't show warnings etc like Eclipse does.  Also, the window cant be moved, so when you view problems (aka compilation errors), you cant view your project.

Comment: Where do you find the "View as Combox of the Project view" option?

Comment: This does not work 100% of the time. I only get some errors.

Answer (score 31):

A more up to date answer for anyone else who comes across this:

(from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html, §[Auto-compilation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html#15af89fd); click for screenshots)

**Compile automatically:**

> To enable automatic compilation, navigate to **Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler** and select the **Build project automatically** option

**Show all errors in one place:**

> The **Problems tool window** appears if the **Make project automatically** option is enabled in the Compiler settings. It shows a list of problems that were detected on project compilation.

**Use the Eclipse compiler:**
This is actually bundled in IntelliJ. It gives much more useful error messages, in my opinion, and, according to [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190612165824/https://blog.dripstat.com/why-you-should-use-the-eclipse-compiler-in/), it's much faster since it was designed to run in the background of an IDE and uses incremental compilation.

> While Eclipse uses its own compiler, IntelliJ IDEA uses the javac compiler bundled with the project JDK. If you must use the Eclipse compiler, navigate to **Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler** and select it...
> The biggest difference between the Eclipse and javac compilers is that the Eclipse compiler is more tolerant to errors, and sometimes lets you run code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help with Android projects, probably because compilation is deferred to gradle.

There's an IntelliJ feature request for this here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68854

Comment: To initially access the 'settings' - CTRL+ALT+S (or File > Settings)

Comment: not working. it underlines the classes in project view, but does not show any item in Problems view

Answer (score 21):

On my system (IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.5), it was not sufficient to enable "Make Project Automatically". I also had to use the menu item "View, Tool Windows, Problems" to see the problems tool window at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Opening the problems tool window]

Comment: This simple answer helped me, but the path was `View, Tool Windows, messages`

Comment: Interesting… In IntelliJ 2019.1, I see neither a `Problems` item nor a `Messages` item in the `View` > `Tool Windows` menu.

Comment: Unfortunately this is missing in my version of intellij (ultimate 2018.3)

Answer (score 0):

You should disable Power Save Mode

For me I clicked over this button

[image]

then disable Power Save Mode

Answer (score 0):

the "problem view" mentioned in previous answers was helpful, but i saw it didn't catch all the errors in project. After running application, it began populating other classes that had issues but didn't appear at first in that problems view.

Comment: [Just as a note, this should be a comment not an answer, because it doesn't answer the question.]

Answer (score 0):

I my case I didn't set `Source Root` at the `src` folder. I make a typo to set as `Resources Root`. after fix it by `right click at src folder > Mark Directory as > Source Root`, the compile error shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Step One : Open Problems View(Alt+6)
2. Step Two : Enable Wide-View
   (Top of View Options)
3. Step Three : In tab Project Errors Click Snipp
   and Analyze Your project for finding any Problems Cat by File Type
   And Other Stuff that Programmers need!