# How show error in all modules with intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

1. Make project automatically
2. Compile independent modules in parallel
3. Build project automatically
4. Registry enable compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running

There is 8 modules in my project, I have tried above all, but it only work in one module.

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 ultimate edition for Mac

Comment: Note that if you build using javac compiler - it stops on 1st error. If you want to continue building even if there is a error, you can use Eclipse compiler in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler | **Use compiler**.

Comment: See also this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777445/2000323

Comment: Unfortunately, it just not work for me. I  think there are too many modules in my project. It works when I take them apart.