# IntelliJ - problems view doesn't show any compile errors but underlines classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

IntelliJ Problems view does not show compile errors, even it underlines the classes in project view.

I've already tried many solution found (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777445/1386911)), switched to Eclipse compiler, but nothing solved the problem.

[image]

Version: 2021.2.3 (Community Edition)Build #IC-212.5457.46 built on October 12, 2021

Comment: Does the build fail with errors, but they are not displayed in the project view? Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: Displayed in project view (as underlined classes), but NOT displayed in "problems" view to navigate between the errors that would be handy (like in eclipse). If this is not the expected behaviour I file the bug for you.

Comment: This is definitely not an expected behavior and we are not able to reproduce it: https://i.imgur.com/ERiVEz5.png.

Comment: This happens when the error's location is in a source NOT currently open in the editor tabs (for example making a referenced public method private). And always this is the behavior for me. https://imgur.com/a/ebLXdhH

Comment: Make sure you use the latest IDE version and the project wide error analysis is enabled, the errors in all the files will be shown (even for those that are not currently open): https://i.imgur.com/8yvW5lF.png.

Comment: Thanks, but I have latest, and don't have that button for "wide error analysis": https://imgur.com/a/OpodTEA

Comment: Not sure why, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-and-project-analysis.html#project-wide-analysis. Please report a bug with the logs/sample project if it still doesn't work for you.