# How do i check the errors of the whole project? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I was using visual studio,  in the one of the tabs it was a list of error of the entire project

But now I cannot find the equivalent of that windows, I can only watch the errors of the actual File

[image]

And the only way to know if there is another error I just gotta run the project and waste too much time.

Is there a way to see the errors of the whole project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this view also you can go there pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>

[image]

Also there's a short cut with <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> that jumps into that window showing the errors.

Another good question for this has been asnwered by [Ashutosh Jindal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325742/ashutosh-jindal) at [How to view the list of compile errors in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366569/4385913)

Answer (score 0):

- Hoover your mouse over the red circle and click it.
- A new view will appear at the bottom of your main window.
- Double clicking any of the listed errors will take you to that file and line in your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. `code -> inspect code`
   [Inspect code tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA2jd.png)

[image]

2. Specify Inspection Scope
   [Specify Inspection Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xFE8.png)

[image]

3. Problem in whole project
   [Problem in whole project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4HDr.png)

[image]